# UBUNTU 20.04 - Netplan is no longer present

Tags: ubuntu, netplan

After running a PURGE on the system, NETPLAN is no longer present on the HD. So from terminal invoking the command `netplan apply` I get `netplan: command not found`. Naturally the network functionality is gone and obviously I can no longer use `apt install netplan`, or other such remedies. Is there any way, maybe with a minimal cd, without having to reinstall the software from scratch?

Comment: I did a `apt-get autoremove`, same happened to me

Answer (score 4):

When you say "after running a PURGE on the system", do you mean `apt purge` or something different? If you did something like `apt purge *`, that will attempt to remove all software packages from the system. That is the equivalent of removing all bricks from a house that is made out of bricks; that's not a good idea.

If you just purged the `netplan` package only, that package is only the highest-level tool in configuring the network settings. If you know the IP address parameters to use, you could set them manually (non-persistently) using lower-level commands like `ip address add <IP address>/<mask length>`, `ip route add default via <gateway IP address>` and `resolvectl` to add at least one DNS server address. Then you should be able to use `apt install netplan` as usual, reconfigure your network settings in the normal, persistent manner, apply them, and proceed normally from there.

If you have within your reach another computer with a working internet connection, there is another way:

Go to the other computer, use its web browser to visit the [Ubuntu Packages Search site (https://packages.ubuntu.com)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/).

Find the [netplan.io package for your distribution](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/netplan.io) and download the appropriate version for your system architecture.

Use some removable media to transfer it to the system with the missing `netplan`.

Use `sudo dpkg -i netplan.io_0.99-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb` to directly install the package you downloaded.

If it reports dependency errors, go back and download the missing dependency packages too, and install them the same way. But if you have to do that, your system may be missing a lot of other important packages too, and reinstalling the OS might actually be quicker than installing the missing packages one by one.

Comment: Yes, i made this command: `apt purge lasso`. I must admit that before I posted the request here, I searched far and wide, and no one has ever been able to give the solution for the same case.  Tnx 'u very mutch. You solved my problem

Comment: If this solved your problem, please take a moment to mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The *NetPlan* package name is ***netplan.io*** (*22.04*: [[Ubuntu.Packages]: Package: netplan.io](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/net/netplan.io), same on *18.04*), so you should install it (automatically) via:

```bash
sudo apt install netplan.io
```

Example:

```bash
(qaic-env) [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/Unix/q0625684]> ~/sopr.sh 
### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###

[064bit prompt]> cat /etc/lsb-release | grep DES
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS"
[064bit prompt]> which netplan
/usr/sbin/netplan
[064bit prompt]> dpkg -S /usr/sbin/netplan
netplan.io: /usr/sbin/netplan
[064bit prompt]> apt list | grep netplan

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libnetplan-dev/jammy-updates 0.105-0ubuntu2~22.04.1 amd64
libnetplan0/jammy-updates,now 0.105-0ubuntu2~22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
netplan.io/jammy-updates,now 0.105-0ubuntu2~22.04.1 amd64 [installed]
```